# Training accuracy decreases

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, accuracy

I have a program in which I use sequence to sequence approach as a prediction model  with attention. The problem is, while training, the accuracy is always decreasing at each epoch, like shown in the figure attached.[image]

If anyone can tell me the reason, I will be soo thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot looks like output of Keras, so I assume you're using a deep neural network. The training (epoch) is organized with batches of data, so that optimization function is calculated within subset of whole dataset. The console output shows the accuracy of the full dataset, so the optimization of a single batch can decrease the accuracy of the other part of the dataset and decrease the global result.

The other possible reason is that you provide test set to Keras API and the console output is result of the test set that is not used for training of the model. If it's true you can see that your model is [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

Comment: Thanks for your response , so if it's an overfitting, I should use a test set which is included in the training set?

Comment: Hi Kiko! You should split your dataset to training, validation and test set. Training is for optimization of parameters, validation is for early stopping (preventing overfitting) and test set is for evaluation of the trained model. Please mark my answer as accepted and +1 it. Thank you.